# Postgresql: corresponding values only once

Tags: postgresql

For an ideal handling i'm looking for a solution that makes it possible to show corresponding values 
from 2 or 3 columns only once.

Take a look at this example

```
**id**       **customer_number**       **customer_name**      **product_id**
```

============================================================================

```
  1                12345                    Jerry                  123
  2                12345                    Jerry                  124
  3                12345                    Jerry                  125
  4                12345                    Jerry                  126
  5                12345                    Jerry                  127
```

Now what i would like is to show row 2 till 5 with value NULL on column customer_number and customer_name

but the product_id must be the same

is that possible?

Comment: Your question does not make sense. The product_id's are not the same.

Comment: This kind of requirement is usually handled in the report writer or in application code, not in SQL. Databases (and SQL) are more concerned with what the data *is*, less concerned with how it's displayed.

Comment: it's just because the product id's are not the same! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This *can* be done in the database although I do agree with the others that this is better done in the frontend:

```
select id, 
       case 
         when lag(customer_number) over (order by id) = customer_number then null
         else customer_number
       end as customer_number,
       case 
         when lag(customer_name) over (order by id) = customer_name then null
         else customer_name
       end as customer_name,
       product_id
from the_table
order by id;
```

SQLFiddle example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/700f9/1

Comment: Nice trick ! But I think I would still do it in frontend, because in real world the database is often a heavy loaded resource and db admins *hate* to see that on their databases and shoot at the writer :-)

Answer (score 1):

As said by MikeSherrill'CatRecall', this cannot be a database feature. It can be a feature of the client tool that you use to query the database. Oracle `sqlplus` is able to do that (I no longer remember how, but it is not what you asked), but AFAIK, PostgreSQL `psql` is not.

You will have to do some program to acheive that, just choose your prefered language since the  interface of PostgreSQL with major program language (Python, Perl, Java, C, C++, Ruby, ...) is really nice.

Comment: You *can* do this with SQL. But I do agree that this should be done in the frontend.