# Grouping data in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

If I have a table with multiple entries with same name I want to group only the name, i.e., show as many rows present in table but the name should appear only once and other data should show in multiple columns. i.e., for other rows name should be blank:

```
table                                    expected result
----------------                         ------------------
col1  col2                                col1     col2
a       5                                  a         5
a       6                                            6
a       8                                            8
b       3                                  b         3
b       4                                            4
```

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.2.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please view the tour and *read the guidance on asking better questions and on formatting* in the help. You'll get better results, faster, if you put more effort in yourself.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Postgresql: corresponding values only once](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25872693/postgresql-corresponding-values-only-once)

Answer (score 0):

You could use `row_number` to determine the first occurrence of  each group, and from there, it's just a `case` away from not displaying it:

```
SELECT CASE rn WHEN 1 THEN col1 ELSE NULL END, col2
FROM   (SELECT   col1, 
                 col2, 
                 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY col1 
                                    ORDER BY     col2 ASC) AS rn
        FROM     my_table
        ORDER BY col1, col2) t
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I need to say that I do not have experience in PostgreSQL, just some basic SQL knowledge. It is not right to change data in original table itself, what you want is some 'view' of the data. Usually such things are made after data set is returned to client, actually it is a matter how to display the data (representation matter), and it should not be made in SQL query but on client side. But, if you want to bother the server with such things indeed, so I would do following: created copy of the table (it can be a temp table), then cleared values in col1 which are not the first in the subsequent select ordering records by col2. By the way, your table does not have primary key, so you will have a problem to implement that, since you can't identify parent record within the subsequent select.
So, the idea to archive that you need on client side (via a data cursor), just traversing records each by one, has even more points.

Comment: The desired output can be achieve with a simple SQL statement. There is no need to copy data around or use loops.